# is there a planned date in Google Memorystorage to support Redis 5 or later?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, redis

I'm using bullMQ and I have a nodeJS project for GAE, I want to deploy it, but I saw that Google Memorystorage only supports Redis until version 4.0.14, and BullMQ needs Redis 5 at least.

Then I have 2 options:
 1. Go down to older version of bullMQ -> bullJS
 2. Create a VM with REDIS 5 while Google release official support for it in memorystorage.

That's why I need to know the official date to take a decition.

Thanks in advances.

Comment: Stackoverflow is the wrong place to ask. There is a Google Issue Tracker for this item: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/146063970 which has not been answered. You can vote for this request. The Google Issue Tracker for MemoryStore: https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/5169231

Comment: Even if people has the answer, they won't be allowed to provide it. Only Google PM (Product Manager) can communicate on date of release (NDA rule).

Comment: You can now get Redis 5 on Google Cloud with RedisLabs https://redislabs.com/partner/google/